# EventCallback seems to be changing a parameter value on the razor page

Tags: c#, events, callback, event-handling, blazor

I have a view in my project with 2 nested views/components (the main view contains a tree view and the tree view contains individual 'node' views for each object in the tree).

I'm using event callbacks to get the clicked object's ID property (an int) back up to the top-tier view to let the main view know which level has been clicked, but the problem comes up in the last view. When I debug it, the onclick method seems to change the LevelID to 0, regardless of what it is before the method executes.

```
<DxTreeViewNode Text="@Level.LevelName" @onclick="@(async () => await SelectedLevelID.InvokeAsync(LevelID))">

@code  {

private LevelInfo Level { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int LevelID { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Level = await nodeViewModel.GetLevelInfoFromIDAsync(LevelID);
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> SelectedLevelID { get; set; }
```

}

If I hard code the value (e.g. InvokeAsync(1)), then it works as expected and clicking any level shows the data from level 1, otherwise it sets the views LevelID property to 0. I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm not using the callback properly. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code...

Comment: It's likely because your click event is bubbling up the Dom. What html element is rendered by the tree node component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed that the click event was propagating so clicking a nested item triggered its own event, followed by the event of its parent, then its grandparent... There is no current way in Blazor to stop back propogation of events, but it is planned for a future release. I might get around it with a method which checks a bool is true and changes it to false so that only a single event callback gets triggered successfully, then reset that bool in the parent view, but that's a lot of faff.